# Problem spawning objects in Gazebo, Robotino

Tags: ros, gazebo, urdf, robotino, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new to ROS, and URDF, and am working on a project in which I need to use both. I have gone through all of the tutorials on how everything works, and am trying to spawn the Robotino URDF file to no avail.

The error I keep on receiving is

Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details

I can spawn basic objects just fine, but for some reason this URDF file just won't work. I have all of the meshes that the URDF calls as well.

I downloaded the urdf from the ROS website repostiory which included the meshes already. I am wondering if the urdf cannot find these mesh files though.

Any help would be appreicated.

My URDF is below

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36210/problem-spawning-objects-in-gazebo,-robotino/) by [Gen_Robotino](https://answers.ros.org/users/2585/gen_robotino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-11**:
It would help if you posted your URDF for us to look at

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-06-12**:
What is your spawn command that you're using?

**Comment by [Gen_Robotino](https://answers.ros.org/users/2585/gen_robotino/) on 2012-06-12**:
I am using
rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file robotino.urdf -urdf -model robotino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the command svn from the ROS website, which gave me all of the correct meshes.

---

Originally posted by [Gen_Robotino](https://answers.ros.org/users/2585/gen_robotino/) with karma: 16 on 2012-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0